# Warnings compiling simple SYCL program with Clang++

Tags: clang, intel, sycl, dpc++

When compiling a very simple program with Clang++, vanilla version 16 (not intel version), I get warnings that do not arise when compiling with the dpcpp compiler. I am concerned since I have no way to know if the warnings will mean that my code will be malfunctioning in some way at runtime.

This minimal code generates some warnings about interop_handler being deprecated:

```
#include <CL/sycl.hpp>
int main(){}
```

The command issued is the following, where INCLUDEDIR is used to indicate where the SYCL headers are:

```
clang++ -std=c++17 -I$INCLUDEDIR -c t.cpp
```

The warnings are:

```
In file included from t.cpp:1:
In file included from /ONE_API_2022.3/compiler/2022.2.0/linux/include/sycl/CL/sycl.hpp:16:
In file included from /ONE_API_2022.3/compiler/2022.2.0/linux/include/sycl/CL/sycl/backend.hpp:18:
In file included from /ONE_API_2022.3/compiler/2022.2.0/linux/include/sycl/CL/sycl/detail/backend_traits_opencl.hpp:26:
In file included from /ONE_API_2022.3/compiler/2022.2.0/linux/include/sycl/CL/sycl/queue.hpp:20:
In file included from /ONE_API_2022.3/compiler/2022.2.0/linux/include/sycl/CL/sycl/handler.hpp:14:
In file included from /ONE_API_2022.3/compiler/2022.2.0/linux/include/sycl/CL/sycl/detail/cg.hpp:27:
/ONE_API_2022.3/compiler/2022.2.0/linux/include/sycl/CL/sycl/detail/cg_types.hpp:234:32: warning: 'interop_handler' is deprecated: interop_handler class is deprecated, use interop_handle instead with host-task [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  std::function<void(cl::sycl::interop_handler)> MFunc;
                               ^
/ONE_API_2022.3/compiler/2022.2.0/linux/include/sycl/CL/sycl/interop_handler.hpp:18:7: note: 'interop_handler' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
class __SYCL_DEPRECATED("interop_handler class is deprecated, use"
      ^
/ONE_API_2022.3/compiler/2022.2.0/linux/include/sycl/CL/sycl/detail/defines_elementary.hpp:45:38: note: expanded from macro '__SYCL_DEPRECATED'
#define __SYCL_DEPRECATED(message) [[deprecated(message)]]
                                     ^
In file included from t.cpp:1:
In file included from /ONE_API_2022.3/compiler/2022.2.0/linux/include/sycl/CL/sycl.hpp:16:
In file included from /ONE_API_2022.3/compiler/2022.2.0/linux/include/sycl/CL/sycl/backend.hpp:18:
In file included from /ONE_API_2022.3/compiler/2022.2.0/linux/include/sycl/CL/sycl/detail/backend_traits_opencl.hpp:26:
In file included from /ONE_API_2022.3/compiler/2022.2.0/linux/include/sycl/CL/sycl/queue.hpp:20:
In file included from /ONE_API_2022.3/compiler/2022.2.0/linux/include/sycl/CL/sycl/handler.hpp:14:
In file included from /ONE_API_2022.3/compiler/2022.2.0/linux/include/sycl/CL/sycl/detail/cg.hpp:27:
/ONE_API_2022.3/compiler/2022.2.0/linux/include/sycl/CL/sycl/detail/cg_types.hpp:237:44: warning: 'interop_handler' is deprecated: interop_handler class is deprecated, use interop_handle instead with host-task [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  InteropTask(std::function<void(cl::sycl::interop_handler)> Func)
                                           ^
/ONE_API_2022.3/compiler/2022.2.0/linux/include/sycl/CL/sycl/interop_handler.hpp:18:7: note: 'interop_handler' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
class __SYCL_DEPRECATED("interop_handler class is deprecated, use"
      ^
/ONE_API_2022.3/compiler/2022.2.0/linux/include/sycl/CL/sycl/detail/defines_elementary.hpp:45:38: note: expanded from macro '__SYCL_DEPRECATED'
#define __SYCL_DEPRECATED(message) [[deprecated(message)]]
                                     ^
In file included from t.cpp:1:
In file included from /ONE_API_2022.3/compiler/2022.2.0/linux/include/sycl/CL/sycl.hpp:16:
In file included from /ONE_API_2022.3/compiler/2022.2.0/linux/include/sycl/CL/sycl/backend.hpp:18:
In file included from /ONE_API_2022.3/compiler/2022.2.0/linux/include/sycl/CL/sycl/detail/backend_traits_opencl.hpp:26:
In file included from /ONE_API_2022.3/compiler/2022.2.0/linux/include/sycl/CL/sycl/queue.hpp:20:
In file included from /ONE_API_2022.3/compiler/2022.2.0/linux/include/sycl/CL/sycl/handler.hpp:14:
In file included from /ONE_API_2022.3/compiler/2022.2.0/linux/include/sycl/CL/sycl/detail/cg.hpp:27:
/ONE_API_2022.3/compiler/2022.2.0/linux/include/sycl/CL/sycl/detail/cg_types.hpp:239:23: warning: 'interop_handler' is deprecated: interop_handler class is deprecated, use interop_handle instead with host-task [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  void call(cl::sycl::interop_handler &h) { MFunc(h); }
                      ^
/ONE_API_2022.3/compiler/2022.2.0/linux/include/sycl/CL/sycl/interop_handler.hpp:18:7: note: 'interop_handler' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
class __SYCL_DEPRECATED("interop_handler class is deprecated, use"
      ^
/ONE_API_2022.3/compiler/2022.2.0/linux/include/sycl/CL/sycl/detail/defines_elementary.hpp:45:38: note: expanded from macro '__SYCL_DEPRECATED'
#define __SYCL_DEPRECATED(message) [[deprecated(message)]]
                                     ^
3 warnings generated.
```

As said, this happens with a minimal example; with more complicated SYCL code there would be more warnings. I want to know if I should be concerned and if there is some way to solve the warnings.

Answer (score 1):

When you copy `/ONE_API_2022.3/compiler/2022.2.0/linux/include/` into local directory and invoke `dpcpp` with these includes copied includes

```
dpcpp -Iinclude/sycl/ -Iinclude -c t.cpp
```

then you'll also see a lot of deprecation warnings.

`dpcpp` does some magic so you don't have to specify `-I` manually when calling `dpcpp`. I guess the same magic silences deprecation warning from these automatically included files.

Comment: Warnings are very different from include dirs. Obviously, dpcpp has lots of ways to find its include headers (t.g. "$(which dpcpp)/../include". That said, it is very different from not needing to arise warnings, or hiding warnings (if that is the case). Also, I would not like my question to be answered with "dpcpp does some magic". I would like to understand exactly what is going on in order to know if I should be concerned.

Comment: Deprecated warning do not mean that program will not work correctly. Just that there is other/new way of coding with library authors would like to advertise. And that in future version of library old way may not be working. Moreover official intel's compiler also sees these deprecations and silences them. Both facts assure me that I should not be concerned.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compile a SYCL program with clang like that.
In order to compile a SYCL program you will need:

- A working SYCL compiler (i.e. openSYCL, oneAPI DPC++)
- Or a library implementation of the SYCL standard to link your program against (but I don't know if such implementation exists).

You can check the available SYCL implementation [here](https://www.khronos.org/sycl/)